# Why us there an "Undelete" button if it does not work?

Tags: support

An answer (https://law.stackexchange.com/a/82351/45195) had been deleted by a moderator.
I cannot comment on that (until I undelete) the answer it seems.
However when I click on "Undelete", I get a message that the answer cannot be undeleted as it was deleted by a moderator.

So why is there an "Undelete" link at all?

Despite of that I think the moderator should have given me a chance to justify the answer.
As it seems now it looks like "Germany is odd, US is right".

Comment: Why the link is shown even when a user can't use it is a SE-wide "feature."  See, for example, [Meta.SE here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/283423/clarify-that-normal-users-cannot-undelete-questions-deleted-by-moderators).

Comment: I did program CGI programs myself in the past, including "navigation bars" that only listed the actions the user actually was allowed to perform. Shouldn't be that hard.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[This help topic](https://law.stackexchange.com/help/deleted-answers) describes some of the policies that apply to the deletion of answers.

- Answers deleted by moderators can only be undeleted by moderators.
- Answers with a score of -1 or lower may be deleted by vote. Any user with a high enough reputation (4,000 or more) may vote to delete such an answer, or may vote to undelete it again.
- Answers can be deleted at any time by their authors, unless the answer has been accepted by the question asker.

Comment: I think this should be a two-step process (like closing a question): First mark it to be deleted, while giving the author a chance to edit or comment, **Then** if the reason to delete still persists, actually delete it.